# Signing jar with timestamp and authentication at the timestamp server

Tags: java, jarsigner, jar-signing

I want to use the timestamp option `-tsa` of the java [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) tool. The timestamp service I have in mind requires authentication. For this purpose you get a personalized soft token to identify yourself at the timestamp server.

My question: Is this authentication supported by the jarsigner tool? In other words: does jarsigner support RFC 3161 (Time-Stamp Protocol) *and* RFC 2246 (Authentication)?

There is an option `-tsacert` of the jarsigner. The documentation states:

> If "-tsacert alias" appears on the command line when signing a JAR file then a timestamp is generated for the signature. The alias identifies the TSA's public key certificate in the keystore that is currently in effect. The entry's certificate is examined for a Subject Information Access extension that contains a URL identifying the location of the TSA.

What I am confused by is the wording "a timestamp is generated for the signature". What does this mean? Also the wording "the alias identifies the TSA's public key certificate" is confusing: it seems that it is used to verify the timestamp (because it's a public key) not to identify the requester (because it is not a private key).

Moreover: The certificate with which I want to sign is *not* a soft token but is stored on a smart card. It can not be exported to a keystore. Therefore I have to use the options `-keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11`. I think that for this reason the option `-tsacert alias` can't be used because it needs a real keystore which contains the soft token.

Answer (score 1):

Signed Jarfile validity is bounded by the validity of the certificate used to sign.

Timestamping can only say when the jarfile was signed.

For signing the jarfile, pvtkey is a must.
For timestamping, no key is required technically, just a hash of it.

Refer the link below for more, 
https://www.digistamp.com/technical/how-a-digital-time-stamp-works/

Thank you.

Comment: The timestamp server I wanted to use at the time the question was raised needs a separate certificate to authenticate the client to the server. The question was about this certificate, not that used to sign the jar file.